# keyframes typing for CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I use the following html and css for typing letters.

But it is not working.

Here is my code:

```css
.animated-text {
         font-family: monospace;
         overflow: hidden;
         height:1.1em;
         word-wrap: break-word;
         white-space: nowrap;
         animation: typing 4s steps(16) forwards;
        }

        @keyframes typing {
         from { 
        width: 0;
          }

          to { 
            width: 16ch;
         }
        }
```

```html
 <li class="indent1">
<a href="#beliebte-steeldartscheiben" 
        onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('beliebte- 
        steeldartscheiben'))">Die beliebtestens Steel-Dartscheiben im Vergleich</a> 
        - <span class="animated-text">Produktvergleich</span>
</li>
```

Any tipps for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span`'s by default are inline elements. You can not set width on an inline element.

You could use `display: block` as in the below example or switch your `span` for a `div`

```css
.animated-text {
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 4s steps(16) forwards;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 16ch;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="animated-text">Produktvergleich</span>
```

Comment: thanks! That was my fault. now it works!